# logging to twitter using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, twitter, http-status-code-403, urlfetch

I tried to login to twitter **without API** using the following code:

```
   var url = "https://mobile.twitter.com/session/new";
   // same result using url="https://twitter.com/login"
   var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": {
      "session[username_or_email]": "myusername@gmail.com",
      "session[password]": "omissis",
      "commit": "Accedi",
      "testcookie": 1
      },
     "muteHttpExceptions": true,
     "followRedirects": false
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

but I got:

> 403 Forbidden: The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

Is it possible to login to twitter using Google Apps Script?

Comment: It may be possible to do this, but you would need to use OAuth. There is no way to do this using username and password and webscraping, as this is against the Terms of Service.